# Running java .JAR server on a website hosting plan

Tags: java, web-hosting

Is it possible to run a java server application on a web hosting plan such as hostgator.com, or do I have to purchase a dedicated server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared hosting plans do not offer this kind of service. The only things that will run on these are web scripts like PHP (and with some disabled features).

The best option is to purchase a VPS or a dedicated server where you'll have a remote access and on which you will install everything required to run java apps. 
You will also have to take care of the security of the server and this is a big responsibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've decided I'm getting dedicated web hosting where I can run a server application.